# change button on click inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview cell and in every cell there is like button.

I want to make if the user clicks on the like button for the cell, it will change the button image.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Result", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell
    cell.likebutton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

and the function

```
 @IBAction func printTag(sender: AnyObject) {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Result", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell

     cell.likebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "clicklike"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 }
```

Any fix?

Comment: A fix for what? You haven't stated what your problem is.

Comment: my problem is that when i click on the button the image won't change and the function won't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` from anywhere except `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The flow is:

1. Like Button clicked
2. `@IBAction` handler fires as a result
3. handler looks up the tag number, updates the model to indicate it's in the 'like' state (the table's backing data -- where's your model? You may not understand how to create and manage one yet.)
4. handler calls `table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths()` with the appropriate `NSIndexPath`
5. This propagates into iOS calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` *on your behalf* which then needs to consult your model, notice that that particular row is in the 'liked' state, and render the image within the cell differently, before returning the cell.

This is probably a lot more than you thought, given your try above. How actionable is this for you now?

EDIT

I see you're still looking for shortcuts rather than modeling the data. You need something like:

```
// This is a data model. I'm not sure you understand how critical this is.
var isLikedAtIndex = [ false, false, false ] // Example only: array of 3 booleans

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Result", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ResultTableViewCell
    if isLikedAtIndex(indexPath.row) {
        cell.likebutton.setImage(someLikedImage)
    }
    else {
        cell.likebutton.setImage(someNotLikedImage)
    }
    cell.likebutton.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}


@IBAction func clickLike(sender: UIButton) {
    isLikedAtIndexPath(sender.tag) = true // !! The model !! Save your data!
    let myClickedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([myClickedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: IBAction handler fires as a result , love your answer ;)
IBAction func printTag(sender: UIButton) {
sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "selecetedCompare"), forState: .Normal)
    }

Comment: That's a clever shortcut in the comment there for the *immediate short term* but it makes me sad because ultimately for an App to do anything real it needs a data model that represents the data independent of the UI. You're tunneling into a dead end. What happens when you actually need to tell a database which items were liked?

Comment: Also, your answer is actually wrong because the cell will get *reused* for a different row* of the table as the table grows. So random cells you never 'liked' will show as 'liked'. But I hope your accepting of my answer indicates that's really what you're aiming towards, and my criticism is meant to save your App, not be snarky.

Comment: cell.likebutton.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: well how about doing this :P

        if let _ = compareId.indexOf({$0 == SearchResult[indexPath.row]["ID"].int!}) {
        cell.buttontag.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "selecetedCompare"), forState: .Normal)
        }

Comment: Setting the button's tag to the index path row is not ideal. It only works if the table doesn't support deletions, insertions, or sorting.

Comment: Re-done to be more explicit about how to use a model.

Comment: @rmaddy: It will work if you use `table.reloadData()` every time the data source changes, invalidating every cell and forcing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to refresh the tag for every visible (hence, clickable) cell.

Comment: @BaseZen I'm not talking about `reloadData`. If the table allows rows to be deleted, inserted, or moved (which won't result in `reloadData` being called), then you can't use the index path as the button's tag.

Answer (score 1):

**sender** should be a reference to **likebutton** so you should be able to do the following:

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "clicklike"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I think that you are going about this the wrong way though. When the cell is reused the **likebutton** will end up being in the wrong state for the new **indexPath**. The state of the **likebutton** should be determined in

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

or

`tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

So, you shouldn't be dequeueing the cell in order to change the button like this. Rather, you should be changing the properties that determine the state of the button, and then calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)`

I'm not sure where you're getting the **indexPath**, but you can determine it using the **sender** like so:

```
let rootViewPoint = sender.superview?.convertPoint(sender.center, toView: self.tableView.center)
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(rootViewPoint)
```

You can then use that **indexPath** in order to figure out which instance of your model needs to be changed, make the changes, and then call:

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```